# Skip batch job if running

Tags: apex-code

I have two batchable apex scripts that create a dataset for reporting.  The first walks through a custom object clearing some data elements.  The second walks through assignments to accumulate new values for the custom object elements.  I have a button on the custom object tab for the users to initiate the process manually and it is scheduled to run at night as well.  Occasionally a user will initiate the process via the button while it is still running resulting in corrupted data.  I am looking for the best method to stop the first job from running if either of the two jobs are still running.  Both jobs are Batchable contexts and I am having difficulty how to create a flag and reset it when completed.  I would appreciate any and all suggestions.